# VBA dictionary problems

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have the following sub which I iterate through several when running the full work book. What I am trying to do is to create a dictionary which is written to in the sub and then also accessed in the sub to get a max value. If i create the dictionary in the sub it is overwritten line by line so I can't get a max value , if I create the dictionary in another sub I have issues writing to it. What you suggest ?

```
Private Sub CalculateCoordinates(sThread, node As IXMLDOMNode)
  Dim parent_node As IXMLDOMNode, x As Integer, y As Integer, 
  y_max_branch As Integer, nList As IXMLDOMNodeList
  Dim StepId As String, strXpath As String
  Dim inputer, inputer2, inputer3, inputer4 As String
  Dim stry As String
  Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

  set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

  add.dict y , x 

  debug.print Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dict.keys)

  Call AddCoordinates(node, x, y)
End Sub
```

Thanks for the replies, i've modfied the code accordinly but I still get the dictionary overwritten each line. I believe this is causing it :- Set dctCurrent = New Dictionary Where can I define it out of the sub to stop it being overwritten each line ?

```
Public dctCurrent As Dictionary
Debug.Print "max ITEM:- "; Application.Max(dctCurrent.Items)
Call EntryProcToMyLogic(x, y)
Call AddCoordinates(node, x, y)
End Sub
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
Public Sub EntryProcToMyLogic(x, y)
  Set dctCurrent = New Dictionary      
  Call CalculateCoordinates()

  dctCurrent.Add x, y

  Debug.Print "max KEY:- "; Application.Max(dctCurrent.Keys)
  Debug.Print "max ITEM:- "; Application.Max(dctCurrent.Items)

End Sub
```

Comment: This question could be better structured but, more importantly, doesn't even feature a dictionary in the code?

Comment: The code you are showing is not compiling, but anyhow, it is just declaring a bunch of (unused) variables and call another routine. Nothing related to looping, a dictionary or anything else you mention. So my suggestion is that you start by showing the code you are talking about.

Comment: I've added the dictionary routine which doesn't work i.e. gets overwritten as it's defined the sub. The other attempts entail defining outside the sub as a public which fail dramtically

Comment: ```Dim inputer, inputer2, inputer3, inputer4 As String``` will result in three variants and one string being defined.  Put them on separate lines and specify each variable's data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent overwriting, you can check if`dctCurrent`is allready created (if not`dctCurrent Is Nothing`) before`Set dctCurrent = New Dictionary`.

Create a Function that returns your`dctCurrent` and you don't have to worry about.

```
Option Explicit 'Top of module
Private dctCurrent As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function CurrentDict() as Scripting.Dictionary
  If dctCurrent Is Nothing Then
    Set dctCurrent = New Scripting.Dictionary
  End If
  Set  CurrentDict = dctCurrent
End Function
```

Now you can use`CurrentDict`without knowing if`dctCurrent`has been created or not.

```
Public Sub EntryProcToMyLogic(x, y)
  CurrentDict.Add x, y

  Debug.Print "max KEY:- "; Application.Max(CurrentDict.Keys)
  Debug.Print "max ITEM:- "; Application.Max(CurrentDict.Items)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it is now working as expected. Absolutely brilliant !!

Comment: @user2262031 Please vote for good Anserws/Questions that were helpful and mark the best answer as accepted to help others with similar question estimating which answers should be considered first as the default sort is accepted answer first, then votes Desc.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't actually see a dictionary variable defined, I suspect that you need to declare that variable at the module level (possibly as Private) so that all procs within that module can refer to it.

Make sure that you only declare the variable at module level and that in the entry proc you actually set it to a new dictionary.  This approach ensures that you control when it is created.

```
Option Explicit
Dim dctCurrent As Dictionary

Private Sub EntryProcToMyLogic()
    Set dctCurrent = New Dictionary

    [other functionality to set up call to CalculateCoordinates()]

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks , I see what you mean. When I define it this way I always get an object require 424 when it comes to the add.dict part. Does this mean it's not finding the dictionary ?

Comment: ```add.dict y , x``` should be ```dict.add y , x```